# Any way to end all processes on a particular drive?

Tags: windows-7, process, truecrypt

I use true/veracrypt, and I have trouble dismounting sometimes when an application on the mounted drive is still running (not quite sure which one).

How can I list all processes running from that drive, and hopefully point to any other processes that is using the drive as well?

As it is, the best I can think of is to look through every process and see if they are from the mounted drive.

EDIT: Anyway to do this with process hacker? Trying to leave as little bits and pieces lying about if it can all be done with one tool

Comment: Hi Child of Eyes. Product recommendation questions are off topic here, so I edited your question to try to remove the "please recommend a tool to do this" aspects and instead focus on "how to solve this problem". If you feel my edit changed your intent, by all means feel free to [edit] further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using long list of utils. I personally like much [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) (from ex sysinternals utilities)
The command should look like:

```
handle f:\
```

where f: is the disk where your truecrypt container is mounted

Comment: Its still sysinternals, they just got assimilated by microsoft ;p

Comment: So for the record, it doesn't end the application, but it just shows a list of applications that is using it whatever files that are on the drive. Thanks a lot btw, its better than I expected

Answer (score 1):

Another extremely powerful SysInternals utility is [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx):

> Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open?
>   Now you can find out. Process Explorer shows you information about
>   which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded.
>
> The Process Explorer display consists of two sub-windows. The top
>   window always shows a list of the currently active processes,
>   including the names of their owning accounts, whereas the information
>   displayed in the bottom window depends on the mode that Process
>   Explorer is in: if it is in handle mode you'll see the handles that
>   the process selected in the top window has opened; if Process Explorer
>   is in DLL mode you'll see the DLLs and memory-mapped files that the
>   process has loaded. Process Explorer also has a powerful search
>   capability that will quickly show you which processes have particular
>   handles opened or DLLs loaded.
>
> The unique capabilities of Process Explorer make it useful for
>   tracking down DLL-version problems or handle leaks, and provide
>   insight into the way Windows and applications work.

You can sort based on *Image Path* (might need to add the column if it's not visible), then select and terminate the processes you want:

[image: 1]

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with process hacker? A plugin or just by default? Because I don't want to have a bunch of different task manager alternatives.

Comment: @ChildofEyes: Not sure. I'm more familiar with MS' Process Monitor and Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a way to do this in [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), so I thought I would post it here as well:

You can search handles with Ctrl-F, and in the filter section just type in the drive name, etc: `F:\`, and you will get all the processes that have handles on that drive.